# Xcode 10 beta: linker command failed with exit code 1 RPSystemBroadcastPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit, xcode10

I was trying to build and run the below code on simulator but got the linker error:

```
import UIKit
import ReplayKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var broadcastPicker:RPSystemBroadcastPickerView?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    broadcastPicker = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: view.frame))
    view.addSubview(broadcastPicker!)
  }
}
```

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RPSystemBroadcastPickerView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Looks like the `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` instance is causing the problem, any idea?

**EDIT**

I noticed that some ReplayKit classes available in iOS 11 like `RPScreenRecorder` work just fine, it seems only new classes in iOS 12 could cause issue like this.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the marked question. This is specifically about iOS 12 symbols missing when building for simulator, even when correctly linking with ReplayKit.framework.

Comment: I've reached Apple and they have no intention to provide support for beta software (XCode 10 beta), guess I have to wait for the formal release to see if they'll fix this.

Comment: That's not a dup, and I cannot post an answer because this question is marked as a dup. This symbol is only compatible with a real device. Try to compile on a device or on the `Generic iOS Device` instead of Simulator.